# Behavior on startup times of ec2

Tags: amazon-ec2

I have a use case where we have a very large computation job, which can be broken up into many small units of work fairly efficiently. There could be effectively lets say 1,000 hours of computational work for an `m4.large` instance. Lets say I wanted the result back within the next 10 minutes, that would mean I would need 6,000 instances to get the job done in time.

So far I have setup AWS batch, I haven't used any more than the 20 `m4.large` instances your account comes with. I know I can up the amount of instances requested by AWS but I still don't really know much about what the behaviour is if you suddenly try and provision thousands of on-demand instances or if AWS limits how many instances you can use.

So my question is am I able to launch thousands of `m4.large` instances on-demand? And if so what are sort of times would I be looking at for all instances to get to the `Running` state.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have done this many times with ~100 instances but never in the thousands of instances.

STEP 1: Open a support ticket with AWS. You will need to get your account approved, credit checked, etc. My customers are very big companies, so for them the credit and approval process is easy. If you are a little guy, I don't know.

STEP 2: Think thru your VPC design and how you will address that many instances. If is one thing to have 5 instances going thru a NAT Gateway, but a hundred systems will bring Internet connectivity to its knees.

STEP 3: Think thru the networking bandwidth required. Do you need placement groups or very high speed Intranet or Internet connectivity?

STEP 4: Be prepared that you cannot launch all instances with a specific instance type (capacity not available error). Have a selection of instances that you can fall back on.

STEP 5: Create your own software, I use Python, to launch the instances, perform updates, install software, etc. You can then poll the instances using the Boto3 EC2 API to determine when all the instances are running. The length of time for 1,000 instances won't be much different than 1 instance.

Now for the real world. If your job takes 1,000 hours, launching 1,000 instances will not reduce it to 1 hour unless you have a really scalable software design with minimum inter-machine communications required. Once you go beyond 10 systems, networking bandwidth and communications overhead becomes an issue. Even though AWS's resources are huge, launching 1,000 EC2 instances at one time by one customer is not a common launch case.

I would also NOT launch 1,000 instances to get processing down to 10 minutes. It can take 10 minutes for your instances to come online, get updated, synchronize, etc. This means that you will be spending 50% of your budget on waiting time. For really large jobs today we prefer to use Hadoop / Spark where scaling to hundreds of machines is realistic.

Comment: Thank you for sharing your experience. We are using a docker based app so I don't think I can use EMR. What about the larger instance types with have 32 vCpus? Do they take longer to startup ? And is there any SLAs on this sort of stuff?

Comment: @Snickers3192 From my experience the large servers with 32 vCPUs and 64 vCPUs have the same SLA. Consider it that there are less c5.9xlarge servers then c4.large

Comment: I have not paid attention to how long different EC2 instance sizes take to startup. For the most part everything I do is long running, so other factors are more important. I don't use Docker or Kubernetes, so I cannot comment on running 1,000+ instances of these services.

Answer (score 1):

You can contact AWS Customer Service to increase your EC2 limits (use the link shown in the **Limits** section of the EC2 management console). They will verify your use-case.

You might also consider using **Spot Pricing** to lower your costs. Spot instances take longer to provision.

Sample use-case: [Gigaom | Cycle Computing once again showcases Amazon’s high-performance computing potential](https://gigaom.com/2013/11/12/cycle-computing-takes-aws-to-a-whole-other-level-in-hpc/)

There are also services like [Spotinst](https://spotinst.com/) that can help you provision servers at the lowest possible cost.